# Adsense dormant account to clarify

Tags: google-adsense

After going in circles to email Google Adsense few days ago to seek clarification on the status of my inactive Adsense account since 2008 following their then announcement to retire google Adsense when I unknowingly stopped promoting as a result of my confusion over the retiring Adsense vs Google Affiliate Network. I told them that I would like to reactivate my Adsense and asked whether I should apply for a new Adsense account or continue with my old account which I had since 2006. I also asked them to clarify the distinction between Google Adsense and Google Affiliate Network as I was unsure and confused being new then.

I have not received any reply from them yet when I sent them through the feedback page at my Adsense account which details that I initially thought I could not retrieve my records. I hope you can help me resolve this issue and doubts so that I may start working on Adsense again on my new websites which I plan to have.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly don't worry about the Google Affiliate Network as that service is being retired by Google and the current recommendation is for current users of the Google Affiliate Network to move across to AdSense or AdWords based on whether they are a publisher or advertiser. (See the notice here: https://www.google.com.au/ads/affiliatenetwork/)

Secondly you should not create a new AdSense account unless Google tells you that your old account has been purged from the system and is no longer available at all as it is against Google's terms for AdSense to create multiple AdSense accounts for yourself. You should be able to regain access to your AdSense account by logging into it, or if you don't have the password by doing a forgot password process. If the account no longer exists at all in the system (such as if Google removed it or if you removed it yourself) then in this instance you can sign up for a new AdSense account but it must be with an email not associated with your previous AdSense account.
(https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9914?hl=en&ref_topic=1348127)